# HTTP GET request in VBS

Tags: http, vbscript, request

```vb
Token = aiudhaiw
Target = 88192823
url = "https://example.com" + Token + Target

Dim o
Set o = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
o.Open "GET", url, False
o.Send
```

Lets say I have this code for example, it works, but it only works 1 time. What I'm trying to do is to update `Token` or `Target` or both (if needed) in the next lines and then use `o.Send` again and it should send it again, and it should work right? But it doesn't.

if I try with the same `Token`, `Target` again, it doesn't work. Even if I change them, and change `url` again, it doesn't work.

The only way that I can get it to work is to make new `o.Open`, and it also doesn't work with the same `Token` and `Target` again.

Comment: First and foremost, the code you posted cannot possibly work, because `Token = aiudhaiw` assigns the value of the (undefined) variable `aiudhaiw` to the variable `Token`, meaning that `Token` will be empty. And just appending `Token` and `Target` to the string `"https://example.com"` will leave you with an invalid URL. Also, "it does not work" is not a valid problem description. How *exactly* does it "not work"? Are you getting errors? If so: what do they say? As for why re-using the same token doesn't work: that depends on what the remote side does, so we couldn't possibly tell you.

Comment: that was very well defined, but my own code with Token and Target works, i forgot to add " " in this example, these target and tokens and the url are just example, well it does wrok in the way that it sends the Request and gets answer, but if i try to do o.Send again with the same URL and the same Target and the same Token, its not possible, it just simply doesn't work, it doesn't give any error and opens up, but its not sending the URL again for the second time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `Send` on an open request twice results in an error 0xC00C0240:

> This method cannot be called after the send method has been called.

So you MUST open a new request before you can call `Send` again.

**Demonstration:**

This works:

```
>>> url = "https://www.example.org/"
>>> Set req = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
>>> req.Open "GET", url, False
>>> req.Send
>>> req.Open "GET", url, False
>>> req.Send
```

This doesn't:

```
>>> url = "https://www.example.org/"
>>> Set req = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
>>> req.Open "GET", url, False
>>> req.Send
>>> req.Send
This method cannot be called after the send method has been called.
 (0xC00C0240)
```

Also, to change the URL you must re-open the request. The URL on an already open request cannot be changed.

```
>>> url = "https://www.example.org/"
>>> Set req = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
>>> req.Open "GET", url, False
>>> req.Send
>>> url = "https://www.example.com/"  'this has no effect on req!
>>> req.Send
This method cannot be called after the send method has been called.
 (0xC00C0240)
>>> req.Open "GET", url, False        'now the request uses the new URL
>>> req.Send
```

Whether a token can be re-used depends entirely on how the request is processed by the server. If a token is for one-time use only you cannot expect to be able to successfully send the same request twice.